# comfortable-mexican-sofa multi-locale site

Tags: comfortable-mexican-sofa

Does comfortable-mexican-sofa support multilingual sites. In read me file there is a language change option showing, 
[image]
but I cant get it working in my app.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done by mirroring your locale versions. The idea is to switch between language directories, pointing to translated site. It is well documented [in the wiki](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Sites).

Comment: schneikai/comfortable-mexican-sofa 
this fork works great. at least it translates pages